# Parse SDK for .Net: "You must include a reference to a platform-specific Parse library"

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I'm trying to write a simple client for Parse using C#. I downloaded the Parse SDK using Nuget and using all other methods, but when I call `ParseClient.Initialize(applicationId, dotNetKey);`, I get the error:

```
{"You must include a reference to a platform-specific Parse library."}
```

I'm refencing Parse.NetFx45.dll and Parse.dll. I found NOTHING useful on this error online.

Does anyone know how to solve this?